# Undefined reference to `sc_dt::sc_uint_base::to_string[abi:cxx11]

Tags: c++, linux, ssh, linker, g++

I have some code using the SystemC library which compiles fine when I'm physically at the machine, but throws undefined references when I'm ssh'ing in.

```
g++ -Wno-deprecated -O0 -g3 -I/path/to/include socex2.cpp -L/path/to/lib -lsystemc
/tmp/ccCNdiMA.o: In function `sc_dt::sc_uint_base::print(std::ostream&) const':
/path/to/include/sysc/datatypes/int/sc_uint_base.h:844: undefined reference to `sc_dt::sc_uint_base::to_string[abi:cxx11](sc_dt::sc_numrep, bool) const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

At first I thought it was a problem with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, set in ~/.bashrc to `/path/to/lib`. I source ~/.bashrc in ~/.bash_profile for non-interactive sessions such as ssh.

To verify, here's the relevant bits of `/usr/bin/env`:

```
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
SSH_CLIENT=xx.xx.xx.xx 56176 22
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/lib
SSH_CONNECTION=xx.xx.xx.xx 56176 yy.yy.yy.yy 22
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Why won't my program link? The headers and libraries I'm using are exactly the same and in the exact same places.

P.S.

- I don't have admin access on these machines
- gcc is 5.4.0
- OS is Ubuntu 16.04
- Dependent libraries:

  ```
  $ ldd /path/to/lib/libsystemc.so
      linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe29d36000)
      libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fb9b85f5000)
      libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fb9b8273000)
      libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fb9b7f69000)
      libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb9b7ba0000)
      libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fb9b798a000)
      /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000056093a23e000)
  ```

Comment: Check the output of `env` cmd at both machines. If you have not admin access may be you have not phisical access and may be it is remote server. Is ssh'ed machine is same machine with phisically access where you have success? Or you think that machines are identical. Such error may be becouse library version inconsitance (library exists but functions or prototypes incompatible). Or some library is not loaded (check for default libraries).

Comment: What are OS version, GCC version, and dependent libraries?

Comment: @jww Updated my question with the info

Comment: @CJxD - I test on Ubuntu 16.04 regularly. The only thing I can think of is `libsystemc.so` was built with `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` to avoid the new ABI and Clang troubles. Do you recall the `CXXFLAGS` when you built `libsystemc.so`?

Comment: @jww I don't recall - perhaps this flag is set in the Makefile or automake scripts -- I will have to double check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `...to_string[abi:cxx11] ...`

One of two things...

First, GCC and Clang are being mixed and matched. If you were compiling with Clang, this would be a likely suspect because of [GCC5 and the C++11 ABI](https://developerblog.redhat.com/2015/02/05/gcc5-and-the-c11-abi/) and [LLVM Issue 23529: Add support for gcc's attribute abi_tag (needed for compatibility with gcc 5's libstdc++)](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=23529).

Second, `to_string` is C++11, so you need either `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11`. C++11 is the likely candidate if all other things are equal. It also gets you the new ABI unless you `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0`.

You could still have problems with dependent library configurations, and they could be surfacing in your question.

Comment: Adding the `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` works, but `-std=c++11` does not. I can't immediately work out why. As for GCC vs. Clang, Clang isn't installed on this system and the library I'm using was built with the same g++